# Rollback root snapshot in BTRFS

Tags: fedora, btrfs, root-filesystem, snapshot, restore

I have only **1 BTRFS partition** that contains both `/` and `/home`.

I have snapshotted the root filesystem via the command:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot / /root/snapshots/test
```

**Now I want to restore this snapshot. How do I do that ?**

When I boot into a rescue medium and mount I get:

```
# mount -t btrfs /dev/sda3 /mnt
# ls /mnt
# bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

As you can see my subvolume is not visible from here.

But when I do :

```
$ btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 3794 top level 5 path fedora
ID 264 gen 2296 top level 256 path root/snapshots/test
```

How do I restore this snapshot ?

**Tutorials say that I have to rename the subvolume to the root. How do I do that ?**

I have tried editing the `/etc/fstab` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is a BTRFS filesystem with two subvolumes:

1. `fedora` - This is set as your **default** subvolume, and is what you see when you mount the filesystem without specifying specifying a subvolume. Ex. `mount -t btrfs /dev/sda3 /mnt`
2. `root/snapshots/test` - This is the snapshot you created of `fedora`

In BTRFS there's really no such thing as restoring a snapshot. Instead you simply boot using a different subvolume as your root filesystem. There are a few of ways to do this.

### Renaming the subvolume

To do this you first need to mount the top-level volume, which is always ID 5 and in your case does not mount by default. After that you can do a normal directory rename.

**Note:** This won't work in your case because your OS is configured to mount the default subvolume as the root filesystem, and this process won't change the default subvolume.

```
mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=5 /dev/sda3 /mnt
cd /mnt
mv fedora fedora-old
mv fedora-old/root/snapshots/test fedora
```

### Changing the default subvolume

By changing the default subvolume, upon reboot your system will boot from the new default subvolume. The subvolume ID 264 shown below comes from your example `btrfs subvolume list /`

```
btrfs subvolume set-default 264 /
```

### Changing the root subvolume in your bootloader

How this is done depends on your bootloader, but often the bootloader (ex. GRUB) contains a line of configuration that specifies what filesystem to mount as the root filesystem. That configuration can be changed to boot a different subvolume. Unfortunately I don't have an example to show. But know that this can't be done in `/etc/fstab` because that file is not read until later.

### Conclusion

For your specific situation, I think you'll have the best results by changing the default subvolume.

Comment: `btrfs subvolume set-default 264 /` where 264 is subvolume id should be all that's necessary.  That's all I had to do on Arch with BTRFS snapshot of root filesystem.